# User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, user-agent

I'm still kinda new to coding and in a website I'm working on I made a section with 3 divs inside, which are meant to stand all 3 together within the same line. I made it work but somehow yesterday I might have changed something and now that section alone ignores all CSS I have written for it and only listens to the "display: block" that the User Agent Stylesheet gives it. Pushing every Div down one line, when it's only meant to do that if the screen is small. I've checked for hours and for the life of me I cannot figure out why it's being pushed down when I want it to flex and stick together. Sorry if this is messy. Can anyone help me out? Thank you beforehand. [image]

This is the CSS written for it. It lined up perfectly without an issue before and n

```
.sec1 {

display: flex;
padding: 10px 15px;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;



}

.sec-child1, .sec-child2, .sec-child3 {

text-align: center;
flex: 1 1 100px;



}

.sec-child2, .sec-child3 {

margin-bottom: 130px;

}


.cater-pic, .cater-pic1 {

height: 200px;
width: auto;
margin-top: 20px;

}
```

This is the HTML.

```
<section class="sec1">

<div class="sec-child1">
   <br>
<h3> TITLE PH </h3> 
<p > <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem.  <br>
 </p>
 <img class="cater-pic1" src="Assets/chocolatelayer.jpg" alt="cake">
</div>

<div class="sec-child2">
   <br>
<h3> PH TITLE </h3> <br>
<p >Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Eget nullam non nisi est. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra.  </p>
<img class="cater-pic" src="Assets/sandwich.jpeg" alt="cake"> 
</div>

<div class="sec-child3">
   <br>
<h3> TITLE PH </h3> <br>
<p > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem.  </p>  
   <img class="cater-pic" src="Assets/strawberrypie.jpg" alt="cake"> 
</div>



</section>
```

Comment: Do you have errors in the console? Like a 404 for your stylesheet?

Comment: Not at all. The code I have written doesn't show up at all in the console. And I am 100% sure I've connected my styles.css to my html page, that's why I'm so confused...

Comment: If your styles are not showing up in the debugger, you must have either linked wrong to it, which should show an error or not have it linked at all.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but the link is pretty clear and is the same in every page and it works in every page except this one.

Comment: Send a link to actual page?